# Prefixing variables in a dataframe based on a condition and then creating a new variable to show which variables have been prefixed

Tags: r, dataframe, paste, conditional-formatting

I have a dataframe containing a variable `RingNo`

```
> head(df)
  Place Book.Number  RingNo
1   WYT     2020#01  603701
2   WYT     2020#01  603701
3   WYT     2020#01  603701
4   WYT     2020#01  603702
5   WYT     2020#01  603703
6   WYT     2020#01  AFH5490
```

I want to prefix any of the strings in `df$RingNo` with an "x" if they have only 6 characters. All the strings in `df$RingNo` have either 6 or 7 characters.

I can achieve the above by

```
inds <- nchar(df$RingNo) == 6
df$RingNo[inds] <- paste0('x', df$RingNo[inds])

> head(df)
  Place Book.Number  RingNo
1   WYT     2020#01 x603701
2   WYT     2020#01 x603701
3   WYT     2020#01 x603701
4   WYT     2020#01 x603702
5   WYT     2020#01 x603703
6   WYT     2020#01 AFH5490
```

However it would also be very useful if I could now create a new variable `df$Comment` which indicates which variables have been prefixed. This is a huge dataframe with over 200,000 rows.
So I get something like this

```
   Place Book.Number RingNo Comment
1   WYT     2020#01 x603701 Prefixed with an x
2   WYT     2020#01 x603701 Prefixed with an x
3   WYT     2020#01 x603701 Prefixed with an x
4   WYT     2020#01 x603702 Prefixed with an x
5   WYT     2020#01 x603703 Prefixed with an x
6   WYT     2020#01 AFH5490
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the same `inds` variable again :

```
df$Comment <- ''
df$Comment[inds] <- 'Prefixed with an x'
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `ifelse`

```
 df$Comment <- ifelse(inds, 'Prefixed with an x', '')
```